# Django : Read multiple file from html form

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using Django. Using following code select multiple files in html form. 
**index.html**

```
IMAGE Files:<input type="file" name="image" multiple /><br/>
```

**Views.py**

```
image=request.FILES.get('image')
```

**models.py**

```
image=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_pathimage)
```

Now I get only last file (if I select 3 files then get 3rd file). How to get all images ?

Answer (score 2):

My solution for getting multiple files from html and upload that files in django

index.html

```
<div id="fine-uploader-manual-trigger">
<input class="custom-file" type="file" name="imgname" id="productImgUpload" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc,audio/*,.docx,video/*,.ppt,.pptx,.txt,.pdf" multiple>
</div>
```

views.py

```
filelist = request.FILES.getlist('imgname')
for i in range(len(filepath)):
      filename = filelist[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.FILES` is a `MultiValueDict` and doing `get` will return only the last value as you noted. If you want all of the values you should use `images = request.FILES.getlist('image')`.

Comment: 'AttributeError at /uploadfiles/submit/                      Exception Value:  

'list' object has no attribute '_committed' '   any changes need inside model.py?

Comment: The `models.ImageField` will only hold a single image so you would need to either save each file to a different instance or rework your data model.

Answer (score -1):

i just try for getting multiple images from static folder to html page using for loop in Django.

```
{% for i in lst %}

   <td style="margin-left: 10px;">
   <img src="{% static '/images2/' %}{{i}}.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
{% endfor %}
```